# Imagebox, converting bytearray to image so what is wrong?

Tags: c#

I wanted to make an application which can read data from the webcam. It makes the really bright pixels red (right now). But I can't write it out into an imagebox. So what is the problem?

```cs
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    WebCam camera = new WebCam();
    if (!camera.IsConnected())
    {
        camera.Connect();
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }



    //    for (int x = 0; x <= 10000; x++)
    //   {
    camera.Update();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    camera.CalcBitmap().Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    byte[] bitmapData = ms.ToArray();
    /*
                        int i = 54;

                        while (i <= (bitmapData.Length - 2))
                        {
                            if ((bitmapData[i] >= 240) & (bitmapData[i + 1] >= 240) & (bitmapData[i + 2] >= 240))
                            {
                                bitmapData[i] = 255;
                                bitmapData[i + 1] = 0;
                                bitmapData[i + 2] = 0;
                                i += 3;
                            }
                        }*/
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bitmapData);
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(stream);


    //  }
}
```

Comment: the picture box is not a problem, but I realized I used a lot of memory(I will fix it later).
And I see now something wrong with the metricam because it isn't connecting, but I think something else is the key problem.

Comment: If you want some reasonable suggestions please post small piece of code that shows the problem, whole bunch of commented out code with couple random method calls not going to be enough.

Comment: Sorry for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

So after lot of suffering I leaved the picturebox function empty and i wrote everything into a buttonclick function. And it worked! I still don't know what was the problem, but I think the picturebox funtoin tired to connect to the webcam even if it was connected.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public static WebCam camera = new WebCam();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       if (!camera.IsConnected())
            {
                camera.Connect();
                camera.Update();

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                camera.CalcBitmap().Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                byte[] bitmapData = ms.ToArray();
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bitmapData);
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(stream);

            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }


    }
    public void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You must call Dispose() on objects that holds unmanaged resources so the memory can be freed.

```
MemoryStream ms = null
try{
    //your code
}
finally{
    if(ms != null){
        ms.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: your code and comment are completely unrelated - "unmanaged resources ..." and managed only `MemoryStream` as sample (and `using` would be better as sample). Also I don't see how it answers the question, but it would not deserve downvote as pretty much anything would do as it currently asked.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Have you see the first comment of the question, "smart guy"? It says literally: "the picture box is not a problem, but I realized I used a lot of memory(I will fix it later).."
Also, my code is analogous to "using", the results are the same, something you seems to ignore.

Comment: `MemoryStream` has *no* unmanged resources. The code in the question does not show anywhere that instances of `MemoryStream` are kept alive in some sort of array. So while disposing items is good idea your current version of code in the answer is not really showing your point. Disposing `Bitmap` objects as sample could indeed be useful, but you'll need to carefully craft sample so it does work with image control correctly.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "MemoryStream has no unmanged resources." It's better to know what your are talking about before saying something stupid: 
"MemoryStream.Dispose Method (Boolean). Releases the unmanaged resources used by the MemoryStream class and optionally releases the managed resources."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143433(v=vs.110).aspx
If you dispose the bitmap, then it throws an exception if you try to load it in the picturebox.

Comment: The thing is it has no unmanaged resources - so indeed it can easily "release all unmanaged resources" without doing anything. Note that it does not even clear its inner managed buffer on `Dispose` due to the way it is designed to be used - `ToArray` can (and commonly is) be called after `.Dispose` call.